# How to sort an array by two keys and a condition

Tags: javascript, sorting, prestashop

First of all, I'm sorry for this confusing title, I really don't find anything good as a title.

So, I'm trying to import some categories in prestashop

My array

```
id          parent
556         2
563         2
568         2
511         510
555         510
.
.
.
510         568
```

I'm trying to import in this order. Prestashop gives error because the parent category (510) of the category id 511 does not exist yet.

I don't know how to sort this array so this won t happen.

Comment: How do you have this data stored?

Comment: I took it from an XML and parsed it as an array of objects in javascript

Comment: If there are circular relationships in the data, there is no way to sort the list where you can import in one pass. You will probably need two passes over the list.

Comment: What is the parent of the first item in the list?

Comment: Is this an algorithmic question? I mean, is the number of rows so large that you're worried about performance / computational complexity?

Comment: sorry for the delay. I've marked the right answer. David, it was a large set of data, but it was a one time import, so no worries for performance and complexity, just wanted it to work. Matt, it was 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tree and build the result with top level items first.

The tree is build in one loop with unsorted items and an temporary object `o` for collecting the items. Then all parent nodes, collected in `p`, are checked and if no data is availabe, a root node is found and added to the result `r`, which is later returned as tree.

For the final sort order, the tree is iterated and available `data` is pushed to the sorted array. If a `children` property is found and an array, the children are iterated with a recursive call of `iter` for getting the items in right order, which means the parents are pushed first.

```js
var data = [{ id: 556, parent: 2 }, { id: 563, parent: 2 }, { id: 568, parent: 2 }, { id: 511, parent: 510 }, { id: 555, parent: 510 }, { id: 510, parent: 568 }],
    sorted = [],
    tree = function (data) {
        var o = {}, p = {}, r = [];
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var temp = { data: a };
            p[a.parent] = true;
            temp.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;
            o[a.id] = temp;
            o[a.parent] = o[a.parent] || {};
            o[a.parent].children = o[a.parent].children || [];
            o[a.parent].children.push(temp);
        });
        Object.keys(p).forEach(function (k) {
            if (!o[k].data) {
                r.push(o[k]);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

tree.forEach(function iter(n) {
    if (n.data) {
        sorted.push(n.data);
    }
    if (Array.isArray(n.children)) {
        n.children.forEach(iter);
    }
});

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```